# Is there a way to calculate cumulative distribution function without using scipy?

Tags: python, statistics, cdf

Is there a way to calculate the cumulative distribution function (using the probability density function)? I've seen many scipy and numpy ideas out, but is there any other way?

Comment: Why do you need another way?

Comment: This is pretty hard to answer without knowing *why* you don't want to use scipy or numpy. Presumably there are infinite other ways.